# Creating External Table from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2

Tags: azure-synapse

I have table files in a Storage account, and creating external tables in a Serverless SQL database is taking time. I have more than 100 table files. Is there a better way to create external tables? (Tables are in Delta format.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Delta Lake format, you need to specify just a root folder, and the external table will automatically find the pattern.

You can create external tables that read data from a set of files placed on Azure storage:

You can create external tables in Synapse SQL pools via the following steps:

[CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true) to reference an external Azure storage and specify the credential that should be used to access the storage.
[CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true) to describe format of CSV or Parquet files.
[CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true) on top of the files placed on the data source with the same file format.

The below is the create statement.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Covid (
     date_rep date,
     cases int,
     geo_id varchar(6)
) WITH (
        LOCATION = 'covid', --> the root folder containing the Delta Lake files
        data_source = DeltaLakeStorage,
        FILE_FORMAT = DeltaLakeFormat
);
```

To avoid manually creating the tables, a solution to automatically create the external tables is to leverage Data Factories `Get Metadata` activity while moving the data into the ADLS.
This activity could give us the schema of the parquet files as a **JSON** string.
take this JSON schema and pass it to a stored procedure on the synapse pool that would parse the JSON and insert the fields into a table you could use later

Know more about the [Automatic Creation of External Tables in Azure Synapse](https://www.ais.com/automatic-creation-of-external-tables-in-azure-synapse/)

**References:** [Use external tables with Synapse SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-external-tables?tabs=hadoop)

[Delta Lake external table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/create-use-external-tables#delta-lake-external-table)